# call sendMessage without responseCallback

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I send message from the popup window to a background process. The feedback signal is not necessary to me. Can I not call sendResponse.

**popup.js**

```
window.onload = function(){
    chrome.extension.sendMessage('Hi, i opened');
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    console.log(request);
    console.log(sendResponse);
    // sendResponse not called
})
```

In documentation for sendmessage responseCallback optional function [developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendMessage)

If I do not transfer responseCallback, sendResponse there. The above code prints it.

```
function (response) {
    if (port) {
        port.postMessage(response);
        port.destroy_();
        port = null;
      } else {
        // We nulled out port when sending the response, and now the page
        // is trying to send another response for the same request.
        handleSendRequestError(isSendMessage, responseCallbackPreserved,
                               sourceExtensionId, targetExtensionId);
      }
    }
```

In the function of the port is removed. Can surely be a memory leak without calling the sendResponse

Comment: Please read the description of `sendResponse`: "Function to call (at most once) when you have a response. The argument should be any JSON-ifiable object. If you have more than one onMessage listener in the same document, then only one may send a response. **This function becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless you return true from the event listener** to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until sendResponse is called)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to send a message to background.js and don't want to receive a response in return.
If I am correct then you only need to send a message and forget about **"sendResponse"**.
Let me show you.

**content,js**

```
window.onload = function(){
   chrome.extension.sendMessage('Hi, i opened');
}
```

And in the **background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
  console.log(request);
  //console.log(sendResponse); // **this line is not needed**
  // just do what ever you want to do with the "request", it has the message
  // content.js sent.
});
```